# RSpec have_tag() combined with without_tag() / with_tag()

Tags: html, rspec

I expect the following to pass, but it doesn't:

```
  specify do
    '<p class="qwe rty" id="qwerty"><strong><em><span>Para</span></em></strong>graph</p>'.should have_tag('p > strong > em') do
      without_tag('em')
    end
  end
```

Result:

```
 Failure/Error: without_tag('em')
   expected following:
   <em><span>Para</span></em>
```

I would expect the HTML, which the block checks upon, to be `<span>Para</span>`, but in fact it is `<em><span>Para</span></em>`. Why's that? This way it seems impossible to me to make sure that a `tag` does not contain any other `tag` of the same type:

```
  specify do
    '<div><div>bla</div></div>'.should have_tag('div') do
      without_tag('div')
    end
  end
```

This will fail, and I don't see any way to make it work the way I want. I guess I misunderstand something fundamental here...

Thanks a lot for help.

**Update**

After browsing some other projects' specs, it seems that this isn't really possible. For example, Formtastic has a lot of these:

```
it 'should generate a label containing the input' do
  output_buffer.should_not have_tag('label.label')
  output_buffer.should have_tag('form li label', :count => 1)
  output_buffer.should have_tag('form li label[@for="post_allow_comments"]')
  output_buffer.should have_tag('form li label', /Allow comments/)
  output_buffer.should have_tag('form li label input[@type="checkbox"]', :count => 1)
  output_buffer.should have_tag('form li input[@type="hidden"]', :count => 1)
  output_buffer.should_not have_tag('form li label input[@type="hidden"]', :count => 1) # invalid HTML5
end
```

This surely works, but to me this is a hell of a lot of duplication! In my opinion, something like this would be preferable:

```
it 'should generate a label containing the input' do
  output_buffer.should_not have_tag('label.label')
  output_buffer.should have_tag('form', :count => 1) do |form|
    form.should have_tag('li') do |li|
      li.should have_tag('label') do |label|
        label.should have_content(/Allow comments/)
        label.should have_tag('input[@type="checkbox"]', :count => 1)
        label.should_not have_tag('input[@type="hidden"]', :count => 1) # invalid HTML5
      end
      li.should have_tag('input[@type="hidden"]', :count => 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Am I thinking something wrong? Does experience show, that the first way is more pragmatic? At least, mine would be more performant, I guess...? Any opinion on this?

Comment: Added an **Update** section to my question.